# How to insert a row n times in a table from a select in which one field is modified for each of the n times.

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a script that insert a table from anotehr table.
I have this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5H7.png)

I want to insert each of this rows ten times into a new table. but the field traitvalue needs to be different for every row of the ten rows. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKRSx.png)

how do I do this in sql oracle.

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting to insert each of the ten rows, ten times each (so 100 rows total).  And the traitvalue column in the new table you are inserting into must be unique, such as a sequence#?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with an Identity field (call it whatever you want) and then write an insert statement, run it 10 times and identity will be different and incremental.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to SELECT each row from the source table 10 times, and then do the same for each of the other rows in the source table... resulting in 100 rows total?  You can do that by using connect by LEVEL syntax:

```
with x as (select LEVEL lvl from dual connect by LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT a.sku, x.lvl FROM source_table_name a, x
ORDER BY a.sku, x.lvl;
```

from there you can decide if you want to use sequence objects for you unique IDs or dynamically build it by combining `a.sku||x.lvl` in your select statement.